# sending email with google app engine from remote host, how do I attache a file?

Tags: php, python, google-app-engine, curl

I'm using google app engine to send emails based on https://github.com/godsid/appEngineSendMail

so I do a curl post request from my remote host, and it works.

but how do I attach files to the appengine?

this is my curl post_fields

```
$fields = array(
                'to' => urlencode($to),
                'sender' => urlencode($from),
                'body' => urlencode($body),
                'subject' => urlencode($subject),
                'key' => urlencode('****')
                );

$fields['attachments']= array("@". $_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name']);
```

I've been searching for an answer for 2 days now... any help or tips are appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that I was url_encoding the fields array, doing this was preventing cURL from actually noticing the @filename and attaching a file to the request.

so I had to make the request multipart

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-type: multipart/form-data"));
```

and attach the fields to the request without encoding them

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
```

my mistake on the python side was using self.request.get(), it's what the script on github uses, the one I'm baseing off of

so I had to use self.request.post[], like this

```
attachment = self.request.POST["attachment"] #actual attachment file
attachment_name = self.request.POST["attachment_name"] #string value of attahcment name sent from php side
message.attachments = [(attachment_name, attachment.value)]
```

*note self.request.get is a function and self.request.post is an array

hope this helps somebody out someday :)

Answer (score 2):

You can put multiple attachments in easily. For each attachment you need to put in a file name and the data of the file.

```
$fields['attachments'] = array(
    $_FILES['attachment']['name'] => file_get_contents($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'])
);
```

Comment: oh I didn't know I had to put the file contents in the post data, I assumed the @-sign magically took care of that.... but how would I add them to the email on the python(google engine) side?

Comment: If you submit a POST request to yoururl.com/mail with a valid to field and subject (you can change the sender within the main.py file) then it will send the e-mail. A simple POST to yoururl.com/ (base url) should show some debugging information.